# MongoDB Query Plan Revision - Write Intensive Collection

Tags: mongodb

The MongoDB official docs state that the query optimizer will delete and **re-evaluate the query plans after** several events, one of which is **"The collection receives 1,000 write operations".**
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#query-plan-revision

Given a collection that undergoes hundreds of write operations a second, queries will suffer degraded performance as the optimizer will run multiple plans time and time again.

Is there any way around this aside from using hints? Can the optimizer be tweaked somehow to allow for a larger amount of churn?

Many Thanks,

Roi

Comment: Do you have evidence to show this is a problem?

Comment: Conducted the following small test:

1. Execute a query against a collection with several candidate indexes, limiting the result set to 150 docs (greater than the needed threshold).

2. Upon first execution, mongod's verbose (-vv) output contained the following: "runQuery called Test.demo {<Query body in here>}"

and immediately afterwards the following line appeared: "running multiple plans"

3. Second execution of the same query didn't show "running multiple plans"

4. Inserted 1,000 documents into the collection an re-ran the query

5. "running multiple plans" appeared, execution was slower

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't see any way of overriding these limits on query plan evaluation.

However having said that, the penalty is paid only on the next query that happens after those thresholds are crossed. Query planner executes multiple plans and kills most of the other plans once it is sure of which plan is responding fast enough for the criteria.

For a write heavy system, assuming there are not many reads, and the fact that not all queries are executed till completion by the planner, that penalty should already be reduced to minimal affect.

Comment: Anil thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, our case involves a write intensive collection which results in the thresholds being crossed instantly. This causes (almost) each read query to end up running multiple plans and executing very slowly (assuming no hints of course).